# Add a "with +10 minutes" condition using db_select()

Tags: 7, database

I'm trying to add a condition "within 10 minutes" using `db_select()`. This is my code.

```
$query = db_select('table1', 'c');
$query->innerJoin('table2', 'i', 'i.nid = c.nid');
$query->fields('c', array('cid', 'nid', 'container', 'users_list', 'api_key', 'regions', 'abbreviative'));
$query->fields('i', array('id', 'nid', 'image_path', 'image_style', 'final_image_name_path', 'retry'));
$query->condition('i.status', array('Pending', 'Failed'), 'IN');
// HAVING(Convert(DateTime, DateAdd(MONTH, tb_files.file_retentiondate, MAX(tb_records.rec_record_date))) <= getdate())
$query->condition(db_and()->condition('i.status', array('InProgress'), 'IN')->condition('i.last_updated', /* This is where I'm confused*/, '=')));
$query->condition('i.retry', 10, '<');
$query->orderBy('i.id', 'ASC');
$query->orderBy('i.retry', 'ASC');
$query->range(0, 10);
$entries = $query->execute()->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this instead

```
->condition('i.last_updated', date("d-m-Y H:i:s"), ">")));
```

Comment: Where is the 10 minutes part? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Try using the following in your condition:

```
->condition('i.last_updated', REQUEST_TIME - 10 * 60, '>=')));
```

Drupal uses most of the time UNIX timestamps, meaning you can easily calculate the difference by subtracting the number of seconds. In your case, it will be 10 minutes times 60 seconds per minute = 600 seconds.

`REQUEST_TIME` is provided by Drupal and gives you the current timestamp.

Hope this helps.

Comment: It was the same, but I was getting the syntax error.

Comment: PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '> '1435227342') AND (i.retry < '10') ORDER BY i.id ASC, i.retry ASC LIMIT 10 OF' at line 2